# Saving user searches to a database

Tags: database, search, query, store

My job is to come up with an implementation to save searches linked to an individual user, as well as the ability to analyze this data for business cases.

The data will be used for users to see their search history, and for data mining to get insight in user behavior

It will be implemented on an app to find houses, the scale will be a single country but a possibility to grow global.

**Solution 1:**

Saving the query string e.g. `?price=20000&rooms=3`

Table **Searches**

- All query strings are inserted in this table with a unique constraint and a unique ID. So whenever the same search is performed it will not be inserted again.

Table **UserSearches**

- Whenever a search is performed, a search ID gets linked with a User ID. And a counter for how many times the user has performed this search.

**Solution 2:**

Have a list of columns in a tblSavedSearch corresponding to the search criteria - price/zip/# bedrooms/etc.

Table **Searches**

- The params of every search are divided in columns and linked to a User ID.

**My conclusion**

I think solution 2 is the best case for analyzing the data to get an insight in individual as well as common user behavior. But I am not sure it is scalable enough and whether it’s the best way.

Solution 1 is more scalable, but it will require a lot of programming on the application itself to retrieve useful information from the data.

Are there any other options available and how would you do it?

**EDIT**

**Solution 1**

Searches Table:

```
Search ID
Field (e.g. rooms, price, city)
Value (e.g. 2, 20 000, New York) <= numbers saved as String.
Counter
```

UserSearches Table:

```
User ID
Search ID
Counter
```

---

```
1. User performs search query
2. Search query is decomposed per field (e.g. rooms: 2, city: New york)
3. For each field
   - If field & value combined are unique: 
        insert search in Searches table
   - Else:
        increment counter of the found field & value combination
4. For each search
   - if search ID doesn’t exist:
        insert UserSearch in UserSearches table.
   - Else:
         increment counter of the UserSearch
```

**Solution 2**

Searches Table:

```
Search ID
Field (e.g. rooms, price, city)
Value (e.g. 2, 20 000, New York) <= numbers saved as String.
```

UserSearches Table:

```
User ID
Search ID
```

---

```
1. User performs search query
2. Search query is decomposed per field (e.g. rooms: 2, city: New york)
3. each field with its value is inserted into Searches table.
4. for each inserted search, insert UserSearch with the searchID into UserSearches table.
```

With the first method we can retrieve business logic easily with the counter fields, this will reduce row size from both tables a lot, but will require more logic on insertion.

With the second method we can retrieve business logic with complex querys, the row sizes of both tables will be a lot bigger, but there’s not so much overhead on insertion.

As for my knowledge with databases goes, writing performance is more important than reading, therefore I think solution 2 is best.

What do you think?

**EDIT2**

**Solution 3**

Searches Table:

```
Search ID
Field (e.g. rooms, price, city)
Value (e.g. 2, 20 000, New York) <= numbers saved as String.
Date
```

UserSearches Table:

```
User ID
Search ID
Date
```

**Solution 4**

UserSearches Table:

```
User ID 
Date
Field1 (e.g. rooms)
Field2 (e.g. priceLow)
Field3 (e.g. priceHigh)
etc.
```

Comment: With solution 2 how would you handle ranges: i.e. price between 100 000 and 150 000?

Comment: I would use a priceLow and priceHigh field. But I'm now more inclined to use the solution of Etsitpab Nioliv. What would be better, use solution 2 with date and time columns added compared to Etsitpab's solution?

Comment: Please see my edited post: solution 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the following UserSearches table:

UserId

Date

Then I add **a column for each field**

This way, you can easily SELECT the columns you want to consider, then group / sum the data.

A business case you may encounter : How many different user searched for a price over 20000:

```
SELECT count(UserId) 
FROM (SELECT UserId, SUM(price) 
      FROM UserSearches 
      WHERE price > 20000 
      GROUP BY price)
```

It seems pretty straightforward to me.

The count is not needed. You don't have an history if you don't have **a Date associated to every search**.

Your Field column is going to be problematic. Your table is supposed to make you store normalized data, not key-value pairs.

---

EDIT (to answer your comment)

If you add a field to your search, add a column, existing data will have NULL for this column. You loose a bit of info which is the 'context' of your search (what fields where available at the time). If it is relevant for you to keep the context of every search set the defaut value to "N/A" meaning "Not available at the time". It doesn't seem very clean (you might need to exclude the "N/A" value often) but it's flexible.

Comment: Good point about the date, this seems like the easiest solution so far. But will there be no problem if I add fields later on?

Comment: I see, but what if there are lots of different fields to search for? Isn't it bad practice to have a lot of columns?

Comment: @Soundwave Edited my answer to suggest a way to handle change

Comment: Edited my post again. What makes your solution (solution 4) more preferable over solution 3 (solution 2 with dates). Because I've read that a lot of columns is not preferable. And there might be a lot of search options.

Comment: @Soundwave Check the documentation specific to your DBMS but I would be surprised that it is a limiting factor. From my experience, it's very common to have 100+  columns in a table. If you prefer facts, prototype and benchmarck to make sure this is sustainable with a large amount of data and columns

Comment: Alright, if that won't matter. Why is it preferred over the other method? Because it reduces the amount of tables? Or is there another reason.

Comment: Besides, what if the user doesn't use all filters? solution 4 will have to put all the columns to a NULL value where as solution 3 won't have to deal with it.

Comment: @Soundwave You don't have to explicitly set fields to NULL when you insert (unless you specify NOT NULL when creating the table). Why is it better than solution 3 ? You'll have to rely on your program to ensure that the type of your data is correct. To store 2000 you store "2.000" "2 000" "2000" "2.000,00" ? Imagine it with a local date... That would be a nightmare. If you have types, you handle the DBMS errors in your program just like usual. The casts costs on a potentially big table is also a major issue.

Comment: Got it. What do you think about this solution compared to any NoSQL solution though?

Comment: @Soundwave I don't know NoSQL (enough) nor the amount of data you expect so I can't really answer this. If that's only millions of rows SQL is certainly fine. Archiving / deleting old data may be worth considering too.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider a third solution, having a table with:

1. Search ID (key)
2. Field (key, assuming a field appears only once per search)
3. Value

Then you can have another table with:

1. User ID (key)
2. Search ID (key)
3. Search counter (or whatever you need)

With this model you can add and remove fields to the search with little impact to the database (Solution 2 implies adding columns for new fields).

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution, but it will not let me allow to use different data types for the value column. Would you implement it in a different way or store numbers as Strings? So Rooms: "2" and City: "New York" will work?

Comment: For different types you need little more complex model, with different tables for INT,VARCHAR, etc. Also, to keep a single table (and store values as the most generic type, likely VARCHAR) you can have another table to store the real type of each field, and use conversion routines to convert form the real type to varchar and getting back to the real type when needed.

Comment: I see, I've created 2 solutions from your answer, I edited my original post. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: @AntonioParra Sounds like a dirty hack. Having numbers stored as varchar is a terrible idea in terms of performance and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 2.**

Solution1 is *not* more scalable as far as I can tell, and it has a number of drawbacks. Checking for duplicates is not as easy as it seems, since the key-value pairs might occur in arbitrary order in the encoded URL. In any case, you shouldn't couple the database so tightly to the URL-layout used in the frontend. Also it violates first normal form by encoding multiple values in a single field.

Comment: I see, is solution 2 good practice or do you recommend something else

Comment: @Soundwave: I wouldn't prefix table names with "tbl", but otherwise it sounds good.

Comment: Alright, it was just an example though. Besides, how would this implementation scale on country level and on global level?

Comment: The number of countries is irrelevant, the only factor affecting scalability would be the number of queries.